# CppUnit (or C++ unit tests in general) in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, cppunit

I've written some ObjC unit tests for use with the OCUnit support in Xcode. Now I would like to do the same for some of the C++ code I'm about to write (a separate static library).

Is there any support for e.g. CppUnit (or some other C++ test framework) in Xcode? When I write support, I mean I want to run the tests and display the results in the Xcode GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [Google C++ Testing Framework](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/)? That one should be pretty portable.

Comment: That is a good tip. I settled for ctest, mostly because I'm using cmake, and this supports the Google testing framework quite nicely.